# A truth value error using numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I am working on changing the
lightness of a grayscale image.
However, I have problem using numpy array when
I tried to add 100 to the each pixel value
and set it to 255 when the value goes over 255

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc

for i in range(0, img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, img.shape[1]):
        im2[i,j] = img[i,j] + 100
        if im2[i,j] > 255:
            im2[i,j] = 255     

plt.imshow(im2, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

these are the codes and I got an error message saying

```
if im2[i,j] > 255:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can anyone help me out with it?

Comment: Is `im2[i, j]` a list?

Comment: @chrisz it's an array

Comment: Then that's your issue.  You can't compare an array to a single value.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if im2[i, j] > 255:` ? What's the purpose of this line ?

Comment: @chrisz you can compare arrays to a single value, but you get an array as a result

Comment: @IMCoins if the value inside the array is bigger than 255, then I want to set the value as 255

Comment: @FlyingTeller  u r right. I am trying to compare every single values in the array

Comment: using `np.clip` is the right way to go but just to demonstrate a vectorized solution without it (if you find yourself using a for loop with numpy arrays, always think if it can be vectorized) `im_temp = im2+100` `im_temp[im_temp > 255] = 255`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, you can simplify the code is the following manner:

```
im2 = (np.asarray (img) + 100)
im2[im2>255] = 255
```

The first line will convert the `img` into `numpy array` (if `img` is list) and will add 255 in each element.

And the line will replace the value by 255 of `im2` if it is greater than 255.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the numpy clip function for this purpose:

```
im2 = np.clip(img + 100, 0, 255)
```

Explanation:
The first argument is the array you want to clip, in your case that is `img` with 100 added to each element. The second argument is the minnimum value, that should be 0. The third argument is the maximum value, in your case 255.

Comment: The version using `np` should be prefered to my solution imo.

Comment: This won't work if - as is often the case - the `dtype` is `uint8`. Better: `np.clip(img, None, 155) + 100`

Answer (score 0):

When you think about your error, `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous`, it seems logical.

You are trying to say *Is my array (say [1, 2, 3]) superior to 255 ?* Is its length above 255 ? Are you trying to know if the first element is superior ? The second ? The sum of the entire array? The root square of all the entire array ?

What you want to do, if I follow your comment correctly, is :

```
for idx in range(len(im2[i, j])):
    if im2[i, j][idx] > 255:
        im2[i, j][idx] = 255
```

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like `im2[i,j] > 255` is the same as `len(im2[i,j]) > 255`

Comment: @FlyingTeller , do you mean considering the code, or with the 2nd paragraph ?

Comment: @IMCoins i want to compare the each single values in the array.

Comment: The start of the second paragraph makes it sound a bit like that. It might be helpful to point out that `np.array([1,2,3,4]) > 2` will result in `np.array([False, False, True, True])` and that one needs an additional for loop as you have suggested

Comment: @finites that is what the proposed for loop is for

Comment: @FlyingTeller I thought im2[i,j] equals to im2[i][j]. That's why I used two for loops

Comment: You need three though, because img has three dimensions. Or you use the one liner I have provided